# Honeycomb is not passing the APP_DATA bundle to my search results activity

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

This code which works fine in previous versions of Android but not on 3.0 Honeycomb:

```
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    Bundle currentData = new Bundle();
    currentData.putLong(Folder.FOLDER_LUID, folderId);
    startSearch(lastSearchText, false, currentData, false);
    return true;
}
```

The `APP_DATA` bundle in the intent is NOT passed to my search results activity.

Is there perhaps some new configuration that must be done to get this data passed in the intent?

Comment: I am having the exact same trouble with a Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Android 3.0). Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: No. I had opened an Android defect for it and there's been no activity on it. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15579

Comment: @matiash Could you share some official links to the issue *and* patches/ fixes? Thanks.

Comment: I tested on emulators and this issue exists in API 11 only. Here's the best fix: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14676736/1521536